# How to prove one angle is not 60 degree

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

So I have a right angled triangle as shown in the image [image]

What I have to prove is that the angle C is not 60 degrees. I am not sure if I have to use Pythagoras theorem or something else.

P.S Please bear with my strange drawing skills.

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you write down all three sides of a $30-60-90$ triangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A right triangle with a 60 degree angle would be half an equilateral triangle. Hence $BC$ would be half as long as $AC$, so $AC=8$. But $7^2+4^2\ne 8^2$ so indeed Pythagoras tells us that this is not the case.

Comment: Thanks. :) I think this works.

Comment: However, the error in $65\ne 64$  is quite small. This tells us that $\frac 74$ is a quite good approximation of $\sqrt 3$.

Comment: I suppose this is an impostor of you because they don’t believe in the Pythagorean Theorem: https://youtu.be/c1VwQIBN2C0 EDIT: Wow, the fact that this is a joke was really hidden 